# Trying to create an array of dictionaries, keep getting the same dictionary repeated in the array

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, dictionary

I'm trying to use NSData to pull information out of a text file, and then load it into a dictionary.

First I create a string of the text file, and load each record into an array.

Then I break apart the each record into individual data elements.

The problem I'm having is that when the dictionary is fully populated, I then use addObject to load it into the array, which it does do successfully.  The problem is that when the next loop creates a new dictionary, the same dictionary gets loaded into the array, and I end up an array of all the same dictionaries, instead of multiple different dictionary objects.

I'm guessing there is some simple mistake I'm making that is causing this error. Any help would be appreciated.

NSString *clientListFile = [NSURL URLWithString: @"/textfile"];

```
NSData *clientListDataFile = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:clientListFile];

NSString *clientListString = [[NSString alloc]initWithBytes:[clientListDataFile bytes] length:[clientListDataFile length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSString *returnDelimiter = @"\n";
NSString *commaDelimiter = @",";
NSString *exclamationDelimiter = @"!";

NSArray *keysAndObjects = [[NSArray alloc]init];
NSMutableDictionary *clientList = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
NSMutableArray *clientListOfDictionaries = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

NSArray *sentenceArray = [clientListString componentsSeparatedByString:returnDelimiter];
    for (int i = 0; i < [sentenceArray count]; i=i+1) {
        [clientList removeAllObjects]; //to start with a fresh dictionary for the next iteration
        NSString *recordSentence = [sentenceArray objectAtIndex:i];

        NSArray *attributes = [recordSentence componentsSeparatedByString:commaDelimiter];

        for (int j = 0; j < [attributes count]; j = j+1) {
            NSString *pairsOfItems = [attributes objectAtIndex:j];

            //a small arry, of only two objects, the first is the key, the second is the object
            keysAndObjects = [pairsOfItems componentsSeparatedByString:exclamationDelimiter];


            [clientList setObject:[keysAndObjects lastObject] forKey:[keysAndObjects firstObject]];


            }
        [clientListOfDictionaries addObject:clientList];

        }
```

When I used NSLog to see what's in the dictionary, I mulitple objects of the same dictionary repeated, even though up earlier in the iteration, I can see that the code is creating separate and unique dictionaries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of this line

```
[clientListOfDictionaries addObject:clientList];
```

you can have

```
[clientListOfDictionaries addObject:[[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:clientList];
```

That way you will be adding new arrays to clientListOfDictionaries instead of the same one.

Answer (score 0):

Move this line:

```
NSMutableDictionary *clientList = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
```

to just after the first `for` loop line and then delete the line:

```
[clientList removeAllObjects];
```

It's important to create a new dictionary for each iteration.

You should also delete the following line:

```
NSArray *keysAndObjects = [[NSArray alloc]init];
```

and change:

```
keysAndObjects = [pairsOfItems componentsSeparatedByString:exclamationDelimiter];
```

to:

```
NSArray *keysAndObjects = [pairsOfItems componentsSeparatedByString:exclamationDelimiter];
```

Answer (score 0):

You are allocated and initialising your clientList dictionary outside of the for loop, so you only have one dictionary, which you are storing in your array multiple times.  Adding the dictionary to the array does not copy it, it merely adds a pointer to the object.

you need to move

```
NSMutableDictionary *clientList = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
```

inside your first for loop in place of

```
[clientList removeAllObjects];
```

Also, `componentsSeparatedByString:` returns an NSArray, so you don't need to allocate and initialise one.  You can simply define the variable -

```
NSArray *keysAndObjects;
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you're using the same `clientList` variable for each iteration of the loop. You need to create a whole new dictionary object each time.

Try this modified code:

```
NSData *clientListDataFile = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:clientListFile];
NSString *clientListString = [[NSString alloc]initWithBytes:[clientListDataFile bytes] length:[clientListDataFile length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSString *returnDelimiter = @"\n";
NSString *commaDelimiter = @",";
NSString *exclamationDelimiter = @"!";

NSArray *keysAndObjects = nil;
NSMutableArray *clientListOfDictionaries = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

NSArray *sentenceArray = [clientListString componentsSeparatedByString:returnDelimiter];

for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < [sentenceArray count]; ++i) {
    NSMutableDictionary *clientList = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init]; //to start with a fresh dictionary for the next iteration
    NSString *recordSentence = [sentenceArray objectAtIndex:i];

    NSArray *attributes = [recordSentence componentsSeparatedByString:commaDelimiter];

    for (NSUInteger j = 0; j < [attributes count]; ++j) {
        NSString *pairsOfItems = [attributes objectAtIndex:j];

        //a small arry, of only two objects, the first is the key, the second is the object
        keysAndObjects = [pairsOfItems componentsSeparatedByString:exclamationDelimiter];

        [clientList setObject:[keysAndObjects lastObject] forKey:[keysAndObjects firstObject]];
    }

    [clientListOfDictionaries addObject:clientList];
}
```

An alternate option, though likely less efficient, is to to change the line:

```
[clientListOfDictionaries addObject:clientList];
```

to

```
[clientListOfDictionaries addObject:[clientList copy]];
```

That lets you keep using the same `clientList` variable, since you're adding a copy of it to the `clientListOfDictionaries` array. I just point that out because it might help you understand what's going on.

Also, note that I changed this line for you:

```
NSArray *keysAndObjects = [[NSArray alloc]init];
```

to

```
NSArray *keysAndObjects = nil;
```

Because it's just a pointer that is set by your call to `componentsSeparatedByString`, you don't need to allocate an array for it. That array will just vanish in your first iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Should be added the new dictionary to array. Otherwise it will not add to an array. Every object in array have same dictionary mapping. So it will give you the same dictionary value. Create new dictionary for every object and add to array.

```
for (int i = 0; i < [sentenceArray count]; i=i+1) {

    NSMutableDictionary *clientList = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

    NSString *recordSentence = [sentenceArray objectAtIndex:i];

    NSArray *attributes = [recordSentence componentsSeparatedByString:commaDelimiter];

    for (int j = 0; j < [attributes count]; j = j+1) {

        NSString *pairsOfItems = [attributes objectAtIndex:j];

        //a small arry, of only two objects, the first is the key, the second is the object
        NSArray *keysAndObjects = [pairsOfItems componentsSeparatedByString:exclamationDelimiter];

        [clientList setObject:[keysAndObjects lastObject] forKey:[keysAndObjects firstObject]];

        }

    [clientListOfDictionaries addObject:clientList];

    }
```

Comment: Did you really feel the need to repeat the other 4 answers that came before yours?